# Java 8 Update notification

Tags: java

I received a notification on my PC to update Java 8.  I am doing development and using the latest JDK 15.  I have read that JRE hasn't been updated since JRE 8 and has been replaced by the JDK.  What is going on?

Comment: No, the JRE has not been replaced by the JDK. But it seems you have installed JRE8 besides JDK15.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

(A) You may be seeing the false message of a [phishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing) scam.

… or …

(B) You may find Java 8 to be installed on your machine in addition to Java 15.

Most host operating systems allow multiple Java implementations to be installed on the same machine. Developers and testers do this if they need to test for deployments on multiple versions, or if they want to try their app with an upcoming version of Java.

If you have no need for Java 8, locate and delete it from your machine.

How you locate the Java implementation depends on what host OS you have. For example, on macOS all the Java implementations are typically found in a one specific folder.

JRE versus JDK seems irrelevant to your Question about Java 8, so I’m not sure why you bring it up. Whether you have Java 8 installed as a JDK or JRE, if you don’t want/need Java 8, remove it from you machine.

By the way, Oracle is moving away from expecting end users to install Java separately on their machines. So no need for JRE anymore. In modern Java, you can bundle a slimmed-down version of Java within your app. Learn about tools such as *jlink* and *jpackage*. And keep up with the latest news, as this is a fast changing topic nowadays.

Comment: Thanks.  I am still a bit in the dark.  I stalled my software on a virgin machine.  I tried to find a JRE 15 to run it but could not find one.  I searched and found that I had to install JDK 15.  This is why I thought JRE has been superseded by JDK.  Your answer implies that there is a JRE 15.  What is it that I am missing?

Comment: @WilliamBrandley I intended my Answer to say just the opposite. JRE was just a subset of JDK, omitting some of the programmer tools. Not a big difference. Oracle is no longer aiming for Java to be installed separately on end-user computers. So no need for JRE to exist. Instead, modern Java-based apps now come bundled with their own subset of Java built-in. Read [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdatev2020may-6548840.pdf) of 2020-05.

Comment: I thought this was the situation but I kept running into conflicting implications in my investigation.  Thank you for your clarification!